# How to count checked checkbox using laravel?

Tags: laravel, checkbox

we can count checked value of checkbox using js, jquery, etc. But there is no available source that gives how to count it using Laravel

Comment: If you're returning a checkbox group you can retrieve it as an array with `$mycheckboxes = $request->input('my_checkbox');` and then use `$checked = count($mycheckboxes);`

Answer (score 0):

## Form

```
<form action="" method="post">
    @csrf
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbis[]" value="programming"> prog<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbis[]" value="circket"> cricket<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="hobbis[]" value="football"> football<br>
<input type="submit" value="sub">
</form>
```

## laravel

```
Route::post('/store', function (Request $req) {
    return count($req->hobbis);
});
```

Comment: is there any method to do this without use route::post